# How remove item from RecyclerView with delay

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview

I would to create chat list with animatoin with delay (20s). After this time each item should dissapear with fading out animation.

It is no problem if I using `RecyclerView` without scrolling.
I override method in adapter and all work fine.

```
@Override
    public void onViewAttachedToWindow(final ViewHolder holder) {
        if(holder.alpha == null) {

            holder.alpha = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(holder.itemView, View.ALPHA, 1f, 0f);

            holder.alpha.setDuration(300);
            holder.alpha.setStartDelay(20000);
            holder.alpha.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                holder.profilePic.setEnabled(false);
                holder.messageContainer.setEnabled(false);
                    if (items.size() > 0) {
                        items.remove(0);
                        notifyItemRemoved(0);
                    }

                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

                }
            });
            holder.alpha.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewDetachedFromWindow(ViewHolder holder) {
        if(holder.alpha != null) {
            holder.alpha.cancel();
            holder.alpha = null;
        }
    }
```

I am displaying 6 messages in recycler view.

Problem is when scrolling is enabled. (I am not using method `onViewDetachedFromWindow` for enabled scrolling). If I use solution (up) then I recevied reused `ViewHolder` with animations. Each `itemView` from `ViewHolder holder` has animation. If recevied 7th messege then this message already has animation from reused holder. But animation in `onViewAttachedToWindow` is adding again for the same view.

I cannot finde solution to animation each message in `RecyclerView`. I tried use `LayoutAnimationController` to animation each child or using `LayoutManager` for the same.

Test movie:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/1sxdonpasq6lf0o/IMG_0262.MOV?dl=0

Any idea?

[Edit:]

```
// Hnalder to remove item from RecyclerView
Handler removeItems = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
           if(adapter != null && adapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
               adapter.removeFirst();
           }
        }
    };

... 
//Fragment::initRecyclerView
...
chatView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
chatView.setAdapter(adapter);
chatView.setItemAnimator(new ChatItemAnimator());


//ChatAdapter::removeFirst()
public void removeFirst() {
    items.removeFirst();
    notifyItemRemoved(0);
}

//ChatItemAnimator 
public class ChatItemAnimator extends BaseItemAnimator {
    @Override
    protected void animateRemoveImpl(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
        ViewCompat.animate(holder.itemView)
                .alpha(0)
                .setDuration(300)
                .setListener(new DefaultRemoveVpaListener(holder))
                .start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a pretty similar case, So I suggest you do the following:

1- Create a customview for you chatListItem with a CountdownTimer.

2- Start the timer using a startTimer() method within your customview class and you destroy the item on finished.

3- Use this [recyler animation library](https://github.com/wasabeef/recyclerview-animators) to animate your items on ItemRemoved.

Comment: You are right about using custom view e.g: `LinearLayout` (without reusing views). Probably this problem dissappear. But performence will be not good. I am using this library.

Comment: Thx Boukharist. I am using handler with delay just remove item and fadeout animation. But after remove it look like a couple of message cumulated in one because fadeout dosne't finish yet but all item in recycler view are going up because first element is removed. (I have always removed first element - older). Any idea how to start animated before remove?

Comment: Can you show me your code. in case you are using an animation with listener i think you should notify the recycler adapter onAnimationFinished()

Comment: sure give me couple of seconds

Comment: I'm sorry I can't test your code right now, but try to use the library I put in my original answer,it's easier to use as it already has the fade animation you want, I already used it and it's working just fine onRemove.

Comment: another thing is that when you notify the adapter I think you should notify the whole list , because when you remove the first item all the items change their order.
so I suggest `notifyItemRangeChanged(position, list.size());`